# Regex - how can I get the last tag in this string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
"<li style="-moz-float-edge: content-box">... that in <i><b><a href="/wiki/La%C3%9Ft_uns_sorgen,_la%C3%9Ft_uns_wachen,_BWV_213" title="Lat uns sorgen, lat uns wachen, BWV 213">Die Wahl des Herkules</a></b></i>, Hercules must choose between the good cop and the bad cop?<br style="clear:both;" />"
```

and I want to get the **last tag**

```
"<br style="clear:both;" />"
```

My re - `r'[<]([\w]+\b)(.^<)+[/][>]'` doesn't work. I expected to find match by excluding `'<'` symbol.

https://regex101.com/r/BDD30S/1

Comment: Why regex? Use a proper HTML parser for such tasks.

Comment: In my task I am forced to do regex.

Comment: Agreed. Regex is a horrible way of parsing HTML, given HTML has so many edge cases, semi-enforced rules and every browser treating broken code differently.

Comment: Consider using Beautiful Soup in Python

Comment: `r'<br.*$'` - should work : https://regex101.com/r/Ht5LIO/1

Comment: This would also work - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gOA6DS/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use regex, do this:

`(<[^<>]+>)[^<>]*$ /m`

1. Use the /`m` flag along with `$` anchor to mark the end line
2. `[^<>]+` captures everything inside the HTML tag
3. `[^<>]*` ensures that there can be stuff between the last tag and the end of the line
4. The expected result is available in the capturing group

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/myhUvQ/1)

Answer (score 3):

### Note: Using Regex to parse HTML is a terrible idea!

However, I can not resist a challenge, so here goes:

```
import re

haystack = '<li style="-moz-float-edge: content-box">... that in <i><b><a href="/wiki/La%C3%9Ft_uns_sorgen,_la%C3%9Ft_uns_wachen,_BWV_213" title="Lat uns sorgen, lat uns wachen, BWV 213">Die Wahl des Herkules</a></b></i>, Hercules must choose between the good cop and the bad cop?<br style="clear:both;" />'

needle = r'(<[^<>]*>)'
matches = re.findall(needle, haystack)
if matches:
  print(matches[-1])
```

This code finds the last non-nested tag. It fails horribly if the element has `<` or `>` anywhere in its attributes or text content.
If you had an opening and a closing tag for an element, this would find only the closing tag.

> <br style="clear:both;" />

Answer (score 1):

To get the last tag on the same line:

```
.*(<[^<>\n]*>)
```

**Explanation**

- `.*` Match the whole line
- `(<[^<>\n]*>)` Capture in group 1 `<...>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dziz2q/1)

---

The last tag in all lines:

```
[\s\S]*(<[^<>]+>)
```

**Explanation**

- `[\s\S]*` Match all characters
- `(<[^<>]+>)` Capture in group 1 `<...>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LndSvW/1)

Answer (score -1):

This finds the last tag as requested:

**Regex:**
`r'<br.*$'`

#### Code:

```
import re

my_string = '<li style="-moz-float-edge: content-box">... that in <i><b><a href="/wiki/La%C3%9Ft_uns_sorgen,_la%C3%9Ft_uns_wachen,_BWV_213" title="Lat uns sorgen, lat uns wachen, BWV 213">Die Wahl des Herkules</a></b></i>, Hercules must choose between the good cop and the bad cop?<br style="clear:both;" />'

last_tag = re.search(r'<br.*$', my_string)

print(last_tag[0])
```

#### Output:

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

Comment: The tag may not necessarily be `<br>`